# CouchDB map/reduce function to show limited results for a user by date

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb, reduce, nosql

I am one of many SQL users who probably have a hard time transitioning to the NoSQL world, and I have a scenario, where I have tonnes of entries in my database, but I would only like to get the most recent ones, which is easy, but then it should all be for the same user. I'm sure it's simple, but after loads of trial and error without a good solution, I'm asking you for help!

So, my keys look like this.. (because I'm thinking that's the way to go!)

```
emit([doc.eventTime, doc.userId], doc);
```

My question then is, how would I go about only getting the 10 last results from CouchDB? For that one specific user. The reason why I include the time as key, is because I think that's the simplest way to sort the results descending, as I want the ten last actions, for example.

If I had to do it in SQL i'd do this, to give you an exact example.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE userId = ID ORDER BY eventTime DESC LIMIT 10
```

I hope someone out there can help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your key to:

```
emit([doc.userId, doc.eventTime], null);
```

Query with:

```
view?descending=true&startkey=[<user id>,{}]&endkey=[<user id>]&limit=10
```

Comment: That actually ALMOST worked :-)
It only sorts in the results returned though, meaning that it doesn't actually give me the most recent results, it just seems to give me "random" 10 results, and then sorts by date in those 10 results. But yea, it was close, you got me all excited :P

Comment: Sorry, you were right. I was wrong and forgot to write "1" and simply wrote 1 as ID. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

So add something like this to a view...

```
"test": {
           "map": "function(doc) { key = doc.userId; value = {'time': doc.eventTime, 'userid': doc.userId}; emit(key, value)}"
       }
```

And then call the view...(assuming userId = "123"

http://192.168.xxx.xxx:5984/dbname/_design/docname/_view/test?key="123"&limit=10

You will need to add some logic to the map to get the most recent, as I don't believe order is preserved in any manner.

Comment: Yea that is pretty much what I was thinking as well, but I was hoping you could somehow use the reduce functionality to do what I'd like, but maybe that's whishful thinking.. I'd really like everything to be handled on the CouchDB side of things, as I otherwise would have to retrieve way to many results.